# AmazonS3ClientBuilder not responding

Tags: java, amazon-s3, aws-java-sdk

I'm trying to upload my object to s3 bucket, but no response is getting back from client builder.

```
CompletableFuture.runAsync(()->{
        try {
            //runs up to here
            System.out.println("start connection");
            AmazonS3 s3 = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard().withRegion(AppConstants.AWS_REGION).build();
            System.out.println("connected");
            //nothing executed below!
            ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
            ObjectMetadata metadata = new ObjectMetadata();
            metadata.setContentType(mimeType);
            metadata.addUserMetadata("x-amz-meta-title", "someTitle");
            metadata.setContentLength(bytes.length);
            PutObjectRequest request = new PutObjectRequest(bucket, fileName, bais , metadata);
            request.setCannedAcl(CannedAccessControlList.BucketOwnerFullControl);
            s3.putObject(request);
        }catch (AmazonServiceException e) {
            //no errors logged
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch (SdkClientException e) {
            // no errors logged
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
           //no errors logged
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
});
```

The server is logging the following:

```
 (ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-5) start connection
```

and then nothing happens

PS: Libraries I'm using:

```
aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.482
aws-java-sdk-s3-1.11.482
```

I also have my credential file in ~/.aws/credentials

Comment: debug the application and pause it when it's doing "nothing" then find your main thread and inspect the stack trace to see where it's stuck on.

Comment: @CausingUnderflowsEverywhere Ok found it, a missing jar file (joda-time).

Comment: okay, I'm glad you fixed it. maybe you can post an answer to answer your own question, or feel it's best to close this question.

Comment: Can you write an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Could you edit the question to provide more useful debug info that would be able to hint that you're missing a jar? Was there an error showing up that it can't load the class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `aws-java-sdk` internally uses `joda-time` library which was missing and not connecting, I have included it and it worked.